# How to write english transcription in console correctly?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, transcription

I want to write english transcription in console.

In debugger I have this `səˈdʒest`
 but in console I have `s??d?est`.

How to resolve this problem ? Thanks!

**Up**

Client for getting transcription

```
   class TranslationFormattedResult
    {
        public string Transcription { get; set; }
        public List<string> TranslatedWordList = new List<string>();
    }
    class TranslatorClient
    {
        private TranslationServiceSoapClient _client = new TranslationServiceSoapClient("TranslationServiceSoap");

       public async Task<TranslationFormattedResult> GetTranslationAsync(string word)
        {
            var result = await _client.GetTranslationAsync("er", "General",
                word,
                lang: "ru",
                limit: 3000,
                useAutoDetect: true,
                key: "",
                ts: "MainSite",
                tid: "");
            var translationResult = new TranslationFormattedResult {Transcription = await GetTranscriptionAsync(result)};
            return translationResult;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetTranscriptionAsync(TranslationResult result)
        {
            var task = new Task<string>(() =>
                                            {
                                                string pr = null;
                                                string pattern = "\\[.+\\]";
                                                var match = Regex.Match(result.result, pattern);
                                                if(match.Success)
                                                {
                                                    pr = match.Value.Trim('[', ']');
                                                }
                                                return pr;
                                            });
            task.Start();
            return await task;
        }
    }
```

And main method

```
class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
//this works
                    var client = new TranslatorClient();            
             var ts = client.GetTranslationAsync("suggest")
                 .ContinueWith(r =>
                                   {
                                       var transcription = r.Result.Transcription;
                                       Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
                                       Console.WriteLine(transcription);
                                       Console.WriteLine("press any key");
                                       Console.ReadKey();
                                   }
                     );
            ts.Wait();
    }
    }
```

[image: text visualizer]

Comment: This is probably problem of the console, rather than your program. If you want to make sure it displays correctly, you probably need a GUI rather than a console.

Comment: can you show some code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

1. set the `OutputEncoding` to `Unicode`: `Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`
2. run your program
3. right click on the console window
4. in the properties window change the console font and set it to `Consolas`.

---

```
class Program {
    static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
        Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
        Console.WriteLine( "səˈdʒest" );
    }
}
```

The result in the console is:

[image]

Comment: @Victor Just FYI apparently you might need to be careful of MS's implementation of unicode according to commentor on this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how (can't vouch for credibility of this as no authoritative source was provided as a reference - just bringing it to your attention in case it's an issue.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this Russian?

If so, try running `chcp 866` at the command line.

Refer to this 
http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true

This answer also suggests a specific (or at least, different) font may need to be selected (not sure if this applies to Russian or not) [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: I have english windows version.
I am trying using all encodings. I haven't any good results.

Comment: @Victor To be clear, have you used this command at the command line?  Unless the console knows which code-page to use, I don't think it'll correctly display what is output from your application.